# How to use same email for multiple users

Tags: multisite, users

I have a very big multisite. And I got a request to enable option that multiple users can use the same email. I found a plugin "Allow Multiple Accounts" which doesn't work properly. I should figure out some other solution for that. I know that I could use something like adding +sometext to every email, so it will show different to Wordpress. Do you have some other solution, that can be done here?

Comment: You need to be careful with this. If you got this working and if you are trying to use the same email for multiple distinct individuals then any one of those individuals would be able to reset the password for any or all of the accounts that use the shared email. That email address is part of the security system.

Comment: yes, I know that, but I am still searching for this solution

Comment: Parham's anwer is prett neat, but I would also like to point out that the email addresses don't have to be real, so you can create accounts with fake email addresses. The user can go in and change it later if they would like to. 
This has advantages security-wise, and prevents problems with plugins and parts of WordPress core that assume there is one username per email address.

Comment: Exactly what I needed Mr Me.  I just want it for testing purposes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `wpmu_validate_user_signup` filter to remove the error and then define `WP_IMPORTING` just to skip the `email_exist()` check in `wp_insert_user()` function:

```
add_filter('wpmu_validate_user_signup', 'skip_email_exist');
function skip_email_exist($result){
    if(isset($result['errors']->errors['user_email']) && ($key = array_search(__('Sorry, that email address is already used!'), $result['errors']->errors['user_email'])) !== false) {
        unset($result['errors']->errors['user_email'][$key]);
        if (empty($result['errors']->errors['user_email'])) unset($result['errors']->errors['user_email']);
    }
    define( 'WP_IMPORTING', 'SKIP_EMAIL_EXIST' );
    return $result;
}
```

**UPDATE**: for a non Multi-site setup try this code:

```
add_filter('pre_user_email', 'skip_email_exist');
function skip_email_exist($user_email){
    define( 'WP_IMPORTING', 'SKIP_EMAIL_EXIST' );
    return $user_email;
}
```

Comment: I think this is the right answer. Marked as correct. Thanks!

Comment: This does not work in Wordpress 3.5.

Comment: @Guillochon I don't see any change in WP 3.5 that would make this code to not work. And this is for a MULTI-SITE setup, are you testing on a WP MU setup?

Comment: My mistake, I was trying for a single site setup. The "Multiple Accounts" plugin for single sites does not work anymore, so I was looking for alternatives.

Comment: @Guillochon Try my updated solution above for a single site setup.

Comment: What happens with lost password notifications on multisite setups? How will this be handled?

Comment: @Tiny Giant Studios I juste made a test with two accounts having the same email address, I asked for a lost password using email and got only one message addressing the first account created. So in this case it would be better to use the username to reset a password.

Comment: This does not allow more than 2 accounts to be created with the same email address.

Answer (score 0):

You can you use the [Gmail alias feature](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370):

- **First WordPress account**: email+1@gmail.com
- **Second WordPress account**: email+2@gmail.com
- **Third WordPress account**: email+3@gmail.com

and so on.

All emails will be delivered to the same address (email@gmail.com).

Inside Gmail, you can distinguish the emails using a filter or a search.
For example, searching for `to:email+1@gmail.com` will show only the emails related to the first WordPress account.

This solution should not break the "Reset password" workflow in WordPress.