# Retrieve password only by login. Users with same email

Tags: wp-login-form

First: Which lines I should comment in `wp-login.php` that user can retrieve password only by login (without email)?

Second: I want try do possible register users with same email. It is possible with [that](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/75565/how-to-use-same-email-for-multiple-users) solution?

Comment: So you will email someone their password once they type in the username, even if they don't know/remember the email address they used to register?

Comment: You shouldn't comment out any lines in wp-login.php, because you should never edit any core files. When you upgrade WordPress all your changes will be overwritten.

Comment: So what I should do for disable function do retrieve password only with login, without email?